# How can I find when Android Java thread finishes its task?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have start a thread in my Android Apllication - in Java like bellow

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "startThread: " + i);
                        if (i == 5) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    buttonStartThread.setText("50%");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

How I can find when the thread finishes its task when written like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way would be to have the `Runnable` call some method when it completes, like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
            ...
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            ...
        }
    }
    // notify that I am done
    notifyThreadDone();

private void notifyThreadDone() {
    // Do whatever you want to do here
}
```

Note that `notifyThreadDone()` will be called on the other `Thread`, **not** on the main (UI) thread. If you want to do something with UI elements (display something, etc.), make sure that you call `notifyThreadDone()` on the main (UI) thread by wrapping the call in `runOnUiThread()`.